# Startup security

Tags: appsec, sdl, agile

I'm running a lean start-up, and I can't afford to pay a dedicated security expert, what types of precautions can I take? These would need to be cheap, simple to implement, and require minimal time investment.

---

To clarify, as this is a start-up we mostly do development work, so I'm looking for things to make my application more secure. Technologically agnostic, of course.

---

From the original Area51 [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/it-security/9954#9954)

Comment: What is your startup doing?  Do you want information on security for client work, your own servers, or what?  This is a massive question.

Comment: @Toby, I agree - I just copied it verbatim from the original proposal, however I do think it's a good question. It was clear to me he was asking about security on his own development - either product, site, or client work.

Comment: @Olivier, yours was a great answer, but I felt I had to accept @Paul answer. The emphasis on "lean" requires very lightweight activities, and "training" as a single activity will make everything else easier (i.e. a security-minded programmer will know to prevent SQLi without much extra work, but a non-security programmer that has to add protection will take MUCH MUCH longer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Invest in secure development trainings because that would be targeting the root cause of any problem. I don't believe, given this high level of information about your startup, that you would get valuable help that you were not aware of before.

Comment: +1 for training, but I think we can definitely provide some baseline recomendations and guidelines...

Answer (score 13):

Securing your code:

- Prevent SQL injection: use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and parameterized queries
- Prevent potential hackers / employees from seeing passwords: Store [password hash + salt](http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html) instead of clear passwords.
- Prevent introducing security flaws: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use libraries and framework whenever you can.
- Assess your application with a [vulnerability scanner](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-tools-are-available-to-assess-the-security-of-a-web-application).

Securing your server:

- [Keep your system updated](https://serverfault.com/questions/9490/how-often-should-i-update-our-linux-server)
- [Monitor your server](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)
- [Use password-less logins with SSH](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152)
- [Implement a backup strategy](https://serverfault.com/questions/512/best-practices-to-keep-your-computers-backed-up-efficiently)
- [Implement site-wide SSL.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-site-wide-ssl-https) If it's not an option implement it for login pages to prevent passwords from being intercepted (won't protect against cookie sniffing, but at least passwords will be safe).
- [Monitor logs / use an IDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSSEC).

Comment: +1, because this good stuff - but I would expect more of a coding-focused answer. Clarified question.

Comment: I've appended my answer to include some code related tips ;)

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what kind of hosting service you have.

- Dedicated Server or virtual hosting

  - keep your system up to date.
  - use Secure protocols.
  - implement network defense. firewalls/IDS.
  - Enforce Strong password.
  - Encrypt Cookies
  - Auditing Logs
  - use threat models to prevent attacks.
  - Save Session ids in the database
  - Employing site development best-practices
- Shared Hosting

  - Enforce Strong Password
  - Encrypt cookie data.
  - Save Session ids in the database
  - Employing site development best-practices
  - and Pray.

Comment: Encrypt Cookies: never seen any website do this, what is it supposed to help with? Save Session ids in the database: how does it help in regards to security?

Comment: Also I doubt that this startup can afford threat modeling.

Comment: @oliver what I mean is encyrpt cookie data. chec this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606179/what-encryption-algorithm-is-best-for-encrypting-cookies and this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/HttpCookieEncryption.aspx.

Comment: @oliver note if you never heard does not mean it does not exist.

Comment: @oliver it helps with tempering data.

Comment: @Olivier, I'm sure @Mohamed meant "it helps *prevent* tampering data" :)

Comment: Hey, @Mohamed, "and Pray" was mine! http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-to-keep-a-shared-web-hosting-server-secure ;)

Comment: Still bad general advice because you shouldn't store confidential data in a cookie in the first place which is exactly what the folks at SO explained.

Comment: So @Olivier, do you have a better answer? :)

Comment: @AviD done! feel free to up vote :D